# Does startActivityForResult() not work when initiated from launching a specific activity?

Tags: android-studio, android-camera-intent, onactivityresult, startactivityforresult, google-mlkit

In my launch options, I'm launching a specific activity in this case it's called "DailyActivity.java".

In that class, I have an OnClicklistener for a button that should open up a camera intent to take a picture and then perform text extraction on it.

```
fab_camera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
 ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, "myimage.jpg");
                values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
                values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
                imageUri = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, 
values);


                Intent camintent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                camintent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);

                startActivityForResult(camintent, 101); }});
```

And here is the onActivityResult that should run after startActivityForResult executes

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        Uri image2 = data.getData();
        InputImage image = null;
        try {
            image = InputImage.fromFilePath(this, image2);

            TextRecognizer recognizer = TextRecognition.getClient();
```

When I click my button, my app crashes. I'm currently in the process of debugging and was wondering if it could be because I've launched from a specific activity initially? Would this affect future testing if I want the camera button to later redirect me to another activity(3rd one from the text extraction)?

This is the error I see in logcat when I click the button

```
2020-12-04 23:19:54.986 25037-25064/com.example.smartcalendar E/eglCodecCommon: GoldfishAddressSpaceHostMemoryAllocator: ioctl_ping failed for device_type=5, ret=-1
2020-12-04 23:19:59.633 25037-25037/com.example.smartcalendar E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.smartcalendar, PID: 25037
    java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: writing com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/images/media from pid=25037, uid=10087 requires android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()
        at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:1950)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1918)
        at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:183)
        at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:135)
        at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.insert(ContentProviderNative.java:476)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.insert(ContentResolver.java:1587)
        at com.example.smartcalendar.DailyActivity$2.onClick(DailyActivity.java:128)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574)
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Here are permissions from my Android Manifest file.

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Please put the error shown on the log so we can see what the error is.

Comment: Add the log for the error

Comment: My log is flooded with all sorts of mumbo jumbo. I've updated the post. I'm new to Android, my apologies. Any tips on how to better log-trace a specific method, in this case, the startActivityForResult?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On android 6 or above you have to check for permission in the runtime before opening the camera intent. Here's how you do it:

```
fab_camera.setOnClickListener{

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED ||
                checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED
            ) {
                // Permission was not granted
                // Ask for runtime permission
                val permissions = arrayOf(Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                   
                    requestPermissions(
                        permissions,
                        PERMISSION_CODE
                    )

            } else {
                // Permission already granted
                openCamera()
            }

        } else {
            // System OS < Marshmallow
            openCamera()
        }
  }
```

Comment: Looks like this is in Kotin, any resource on how I can translate between Kotlin syntax to Java?